# link in controller rendering in plain text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I was wondering how can I create a link or hyperlink from the controller. I am able to create one but the rendering gives a plain anchor text like

```
<a href=mysite/controller/action>
```

My question is, how can i make it a clickable link instead of the plain text. 
Note: it has to be in the controller since I am creating an ErrorMessage attribute data for the entity model.

thanks

Comment: What does **link in controller** means ? your link should be in the razor view. rite ? Show us your current code and expected behavior please

Comment: Why are you creating it in the controller (as opposed to the view)? You would need to use `@Html.Raw()` in the view if the value contains html markup.

Comment: Hi Frankcky, please show us the Controller and the View code used to generate this element.

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
ViewBag.link = "<a href='page.html'>link</a>";
```

your view:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.link)
```

Comment: **Controller** `Viewbag.link = "page.html";`

**View** `<a href="@Viewbag.Link">link</a>`

Would also work.

Comment: thanks for your solution. But the problem with viewbag is that the it redirect to the controller it is coming from. What if I want to redirect to another controller? I tried using Tempdata, but I am still being redirected to the same controller  that the tempdata resides. How can I redirect to another controller? TempData["NotFound"] = "<a href='~/Home/Contact)'> Contact Us</a>";

Comment: you can pass it in the query string.